# Is there a way to revoke an edit approval?

Tags: support, suggested-edits

It has happened that I've been too quick at approving a suggested edit and realized only upon later review that it had flaws. Is there a way, in this case, to revoke the approval?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, decisions made on suggested edits (either approvals or rejections) aren't reversible.

However, you're welcome to go ahead and make another edit to correct any flaws you noticed after approving the edit suggestion.

Comment: Hmm, how would I make another edit? When I click the "edit" link while there is a suggested edit queued, it just takes me to the review UI.

Comment: @Dolda2000 You can make another edit once that one is fully rejected or approved. Sorry, I should've been more clear.

Comment: Ah, I see; and yes, I already did that. Thanks for the answer.